# Why can i not use JSInterop in blazor?

Tags: blazor

I'm evaluating Blazor (server side app) in .NET Core 3.0 and i get next error when trying to add JS Interop:

"The Type or namespace 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.JSInterop' (are you missing an assembly reference ?), screenshot shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2xTC.png)

Any clue ?

Thx,

Emmanuel Nuyttens

Comment: On SO, add code and errormessages as __text__, not pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Simple Json serializer has been replaced by `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer` [Breaking changes to Microsoft.JSInterop](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/364)